# Как копировать данные из одной таблицы в другую? GoogleSpreadSheet

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица "А" и "Б". 
Нужно ввести в таблице "А" в поле, допустим А1, число 7.
После чего в таблице "Б" появляются в полях B2, C2, D2 данные, взятые с таблицы "А", полей B8, C8, D8.

 
[image: Таблица "Б" из которой мы берем данные]
[image: Таблица "А" в которую упали данные]

Если сказать проще, то как организовать импорт данных с одной таблицы в другую по ID (чего либо)?
Огромное спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно вариантов несколько:

1) Обычная формула [QUERY](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) + [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=ru)
Например в вашем случае это:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Ссылка или ID таблицы";"ИМЯ_ЛИСТА!A2:D");"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col1 = "&B3&"";false)
```

2) Вставлять эту формулу скриптом и после вставлять результаты как значения.
Вставлять через [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)). Вставлять результаты как значения через [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed)

3) Работа с чистыми массивами:

```
var id = ...\\ Получить ID
var arrData = ... \\ Получить данные с таблицы-БД (получится двумерный массив)
// Пройтись по массиву циклом, например for
for(var i = 0; i<arrData.length;i++){
// Здесь через if проверять совпадение id - и при совпадении записывать остальные данные в нужные ячейки
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую